Are Austria to Austria trains via the Deutsches Eck (German Corner) essentially domestic trains?
Trains on the main railway line between western Austria (the states of Tirol and Vorarlberg) and the rest of Austria pass through Germany on the so-called "German corner" between Kufstein and Salzburg. These trains do not stop in Germany, and when buying one's ticket, there is typically no indication that the journey passes through a different country.  Are these trains domestic Austrian trains for all practical purposes?

Note: I originally asked this question which is closely related.  However, that question and its most-upvoted answer focus on the particular issue of passports, and it also led to an extensive discussion on whether foreigners need to carry their passports everywhere in Austria (which is definitely unrelated).  Here I want to focus on the train itself rather than any corollary issues.

This question is similar to: Do non-EU citizens need to carry a passport when travelling from Austria to Austria by train via the Deutsches Eck (German Corner)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo I anticipated such concerns and addressed them in the question itself.  As I said, this question is specifically about: are such trains domestic trains or not? The other question has evolved into something focused on passport-carrying rules.  In your own (very detailed) answer to that question, you heavily focus on the specific passport question.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo In addiction, I would like to mention that I tried (earlier) today to edit the other question (asked by myself) to re-focus it on what I percieved to be the main issue, but was blocked by a moderator. Hence the new question.

Still, my answer to your previous question also answers exactly what you are asking about here.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo not really. your answer states "TL;DR: Yes, as a non-EEA citizen, you need to carry a passport in the situation you describe in your question." and the rest of the answer elaborates on that. I respect that position, even if I disagree with it.  But with respect to the present question, if anything, your other answer implies that such trains are international trains, which isn't the case (or at least, your reasoning there would not seem to fit the spirit of this question).

The entire second paragraph of my answer does not deal with passport requirements at all, but answers exactly what you are asking about here.

Yes, Austrian trains passing through the Deutsches Eck (German Corner) are domestic trains for all practical purposes. There are no border checks by either German or Austrian officials, and there are no police inspections on these trains beyond what might happen on any other domestic train.
To be extra sure, you can check the list of stops to verify that the train does not stop in Germany. It seems that all Austrian trains (from both ÖBB and Westbahn) pass through the Deutsches Eck without stopping; typically the last stop on the east is Salzburg and the last stop on the west is either Kufstein or Wörgl. There are regional trains with more stops that go between Austria and Germany in other places, but not along the Deutsches Eck.

Back in 2014-2019 when I used to take the Zurich-Vienna train a lot it went nonstop Innsbruck-Salzburg
